# media player launcher in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to insert a feature into my windows phone 7 application in the way that upon a click of a button it will lanuch **something like the photo chooser task** where the user can choose the images in the mobile phone.

**Is there a way that i can allow the user to choose the song in the mobile phone?**

Anyone can help me with it??
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in chooser for this but you could get a list of songs to display using the [MediaLibrary.Songs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.songs.aspx) property and then creating your own UI.

**Update**
Here's how:

Add a reference in your project to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`. (Yes, even in a Silverlight app)
The use it like this:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

using (var ml = new MediaLibrary())
{
    foreach (var song in ml.Songs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(song.Artist + " " + song.Name);
    }
}
```

You probably want to do someting more useful than write to debug out but hopefully this shows you how to get started.

Comment: I am trying to invoke the MediaLibrary.Songs but i am not sure how to invoke it.

Comment: @ben you don't invoke it, it's a collection you can access. I'll add an example

Comment: Oh.. ok look forward to your example

Comment: Then will i be able to play the song inside it??

Comment: @ben `MediaPlayer.Play(song);` is what you're after. For reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx

Comment: I want to ask that can the song be saved into isolated storage?

Comment: @ben No.NOt only would there be potential DRM/licensing issues if apps could take copies of songs from a device. (If you could get it to IsolatedStorage there'd be nothing to stop you sending it over the web to anywhere.) You'd also be taking up twice as much disk space for each song.

Comment: then can the song be play in the background without showing up the media player to the user??